# How read separate lines from files?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

```
------------------------------------------------
          Artiles for a magazine          
------------------------------------------------
There are total 5 articles in the magazine
------------------------------------------------
ID : 3
Description : opis2
Price : 212
Incoming amount : 2
Outgoing amount : 0
Taxes : 0
Total : 424
Date : 20324
------------------------------------------------
ID : 3
Description : 54
Price : 123
Incoming amount : 12
Outgoing amount : 0
Taxes : 0
Total : 1476
Date : 120915
------------------------------------------------
ID : 3
Description : opsi2
Price : 12
Incoming amount : 324
Outgoing amount : 0
Taxes : 0
Total : 3888
Date : 570509
------------------------------------------------
ID : 2
Description : vopi
Price : 2
Incoming amount : 2
Outgoing amount : 0
Taxes : 0
Total : 4
Date : 951230
------------------------------------------------
ID : 1
Description : opis1
Price : 2
Incoming amount : 2
Outgoing amount : 0
Taxes : 0
Total : 4
Date : 101
------------------------------------------------
```

I have a file called directory.dat with the contents above. What I'm trying to do is the following.

I want to find all articles with the same ID in a given year and do the following : outgoing amount - incoming amount. So, my problem is how can I find all the articles with same ID in a given year (by the user) and do the outgoing amount-incoming amount for them, by working with the file?

I tried something like this:

```
ifstream directory("directory.dat");
//directory.open("directory.dat");
string line;
string priceLine = "Price : ";
int price;
while(getline(directory, line)){
    if(line.find(priceLine) == 0){
        cout << atoi(line.substr(priceLine.size()).c_str()) << endl;
    }
}
cout << price << endl;
directory.close();
```

But I am far away from getting on the right track and I need some help to achieve something like this.

Comment: Read every line. Detect those with only dashes.  Process those with a *Name* `:` *Value* format. And define *exactly* the format of the input.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't really understand what you mean, what do you mean by ignore them? I need the value of some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define *precisely* the format of your input (perhaps as a [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) grammar). A single example is not enough. We can't guess if `Artiles for a magazine` is meaningful or not.

```
 while(getline(directory, line)){
    int colonpos = -1;
    if (line.find("----")) {
        /// check that line has only dashes, then
        process_dash_line();
    }
    else if ((colonpos=line.find(':'))>0) {
       std::string name = line.substr(0, colonpos-1);
       std::string value = line.substr(colonpos+1);
       process_name_value (name, value);
    }
 }
```

Also, study (and perhaps adapt) the source code of some free software C++ parsers for [JSON](http://json.org/) (e.g. [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/)) and [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) (e.g. [yaml-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/)). They will certainly give you some inspiration.

Learn more about C++ standard libraries, e.g. on [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com/) & [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/) (both sites are easy to read but are imperfect) and of course by reading the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard, or at least its draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: I can't use any external libraries anyway, may I ask how exactly does your example work? I can't seem to figure it out. I'm very new with fstream. A little explanation would be great.

Comment: Also, it's not a problem to remove the first two ---- and the text between them, so I can make it start directly from the articles if that's the problem?

Comment: @user3182683 The code posted in this answer would be able to handle the that anyways. You need to think about how you would implement the two functions: process_dash_line() and process_name_value (name, value)